# How can I integrate Javascript library (socketio) in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, socket.io, qml

After the [C++ socketio library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp) has failed me, I'm trying to use the JavaScript library in QT's QML. I copied the client from https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js to `socketio145.js`.

When I import it as such:

```
.import "socketio145.js" as IO;
```

Running:

```
socket = IO.io();
```

Fails with the error `"[error stack]Expected token :'\n"` on the 3rd line of `socketio145.js`. Is this some non-qml compliant javascript code or is something else going on? I'm lost.

Comment: Any reasons you want to do this?

Comment: @evilruff I want to do this to communicate over HTTPS which hasn't been implemented in the C++ socketio port (see https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/issues/60). I'm taking inspiration from 14463638 where they use a QWebView to communicate with a socketio server (which was deprecated in 5.6). I'd be happy to do it a better way, if you have a suggestion, because I admit this solution is quite hacky.

Comment: What does this library do? If this is implementation of WebSocket so there is already [WebSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebsockets-websocket.html) item in qml.

Comment: @folibis From my limited understanding, Socketio is a layer on top of WebSocket but uses it when possible. It hadn't occurred to me to try to use  WebSockets directly. I will give it a go, thanks for the direction.

Comment: I agree, with previous post, that Qt itself has so many ways to support WebSockets/HTTPS connections etc that bringing in a new 3rd party looks like a real overhead or over complecations

Answer (score 1):

I made something that solves the problem.
I have not had any luck with this at all. I tried compiling SocketIO's C++ library into my project, tried including the JS. But nothing worked and libraries were just confused.

So I took the Qt QWebSocket and wrapped it in a warm and fuzzy coat that looks and works in qml very similarly to how SocketIO works in Javascript.

https://github.com/Dimcon/ParthanonsQWebSocketIO

It works on both Desktop and Android and all you have to do is copy the parthanonsQWebSocket.h file into your project and add in the class to your QML. More details on the readme.

I hope this helps you guys from struggling with this issue the way I did :( :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any details of JS library you are referring but here is way to use your own JS code inside QML.
1. Put your JS file into a resource file like this

```
   <qresource prefix="/js">
      <file alias="DataManager.js">qml/js/DataManager.js</file>
   </qresource>
```

2. Inside your QML file use the following import

   import "qrc:/js/DataManager.js" as DataManager
3. And use JS like below :

   ```
   Item {
   id : win
   visible: true
   width: 640*2
   height: 480*1.5

   property var constellationManager;

   Component.onCompleted: {
       win.constellationManager = new ConstellationDataManager.ConstellationDataManager();
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks for your answer and that's exactly what I'm doing but I'm getting an error when I try to import the socketio: https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js .